# Store and access 2D data

Tags: c#

If I have a data structure defined as:

```
Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, object> rangedValue;
```

and I populate it as such:

```
rangedValue = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, object>()
                    {
                        { new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0,0), 424681 },
                        { new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1,0), 1072301 },
                        { new KeyValuePair<int, int>(2,0), 99111 },
                        { new KeyValuePair<int, int>(3,0), 467874 },
                        { new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0,1), 195066 },
                        { new KeyValuePair<int, int>(1,1), 1171412 },
                        { new KeyValuePair<int, int>(2,1), 0 },
                        { new KeyValuePair<int, int>(3,1), 128504 }
                    }
```

and I want to iterate over it in a coordinated fashion, as in by (x, y) coordinate value and retrieve the value at that point, the best I can come up with is this:

```
foreach (var relativeXOffset in rangedValue.Keys.Select(kv => kv.Key).Distinct()) // Note distinct here, otherwise returns duplicates
{
    foreach (var relativeYOffset in rangedValue.Keys.Select(kv => kv.Value).Distinct())
    {
        var myObject = rangedValue[new KeyValuePair<int, int>(relativeXOffset, relativeYOffset)];

        // Do something with myObject...
    }
}
```

This works for me but it also seems to be a bit *rubbish*. My requirements are to store an object against a set of coordinates and then be able to iterate over them in a coordinated fashion. Can anyone help with a nice solution, either on the storage or retrieval side (or, ideally, both)?

Comment: Why not object[][] ?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Liam - good call - I'll move it over there.

Comment: or dictionary of dictionaries which will give you the same access fashion but will be dynamic

Comment: You can avoid KeyValuePair at all because you will have (as in the example, repeaded values for the key) so I would use a Tuple.

You can then use also a Tuple with three values Tuple<int, int, object>. For this Tuple you can also create an alias.

Or, you can create a Coordinate2D class from which other objects inherit from, or objects containing a Coordinate2D as Member...

Comment: Since some Keys are duplicates you can use Dictionary<int, List<int>>. This will allow multiple of the same Keys with an easy way to get the data.

Comment: [Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be more descriptive than `Tuple`... `Item1`, `Item2` get painful to read very quickly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a specialized class with two coordinates and the data at this *point*:

```
public class XYD
{
    int x;
    int y;
    object data;
}
```

Store these classes in a List:

```
List<XDY> xydList = new List<XYD();
xydList.Add(new XYD { x=0, y=0, data=424681 });
...
```

This creates a good storage and allows to iterate over your data. But search and retrieval times are O(n).

If you need faster acces you should create an *additional* dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>,XYZ> lookup;
```

which allows for a fast search of data given the coordinates.